# Spring Validator

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

Is there any way through which I can validate function parameters of type String using `@Valid` annotation ?

I have been trying to do that but not able to do so.
Here is my code:-

```
@Controller
public class GameController {

    @Autowired
    private HeaderValidator headerValidator;

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new CompoundValidator(headerValidator));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "game", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Game getGame(
            @Valid @RequestHeader(value = "header", required = true) String header) {
        return new Game(1, "Baddy");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. `@Valid` works for model attributes not for header values. You would have to do manual validation for that.

Comment: is there no other way to validate header ?

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have enough reputation to add my comments....writing here.
In addition to what @M.Deinum commented,there is open JIRA for the same, and I guess the fix is expected in 4.3.

https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/SPR-6380/SPR-6380.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it using annotations, but any operations on headers can be easily done using Filters or Interceptors. Here is one example of how to use interceptors in spring [Mykong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/)